# Probability of forming a triangle

Tags: probability

We are given a line with length $K$.We pick 2 random lines with length less than $K$.What is the probability to form a triangle?

What I have done is : Let the lines be $x $ and $y$ , then we need to find the probability of $x+y > K$ ,knwing that  $ 0 \le x,y < K$ . The total area of the square with sides K is $K^2$ , but I am strugging to find the probability of $x+y > K$

Comment: Well, you've drawn the square...can you draw the region corresponding to $x+y>K$?

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you "Let the lines be $x$ and $y$" and "$x + y > K$." If this is the case, then the probability of $x + y > K$ should be 100%, right?

Comment: No :( , I cannot seem to imagine how it would look like

Comment: Start in the unit square.  draw the line $y+x=1$, same as $y=-x+1$.  That divides the square into two pieces. In one region $y+x>1$, in the other $y+x<1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph it out on a Cartesian plane. 
Here x and y represent the same as to what you made them represent.

Now, $0<x<k$ and $0<y<k$ is the sample space with area $K^2$.

Required is the area such that $0 < k < x + y $ due to triangle inequality, now this is a triangle with three vertices being $(K, K), (0,K), (K,0)$, with area = $K^2/2$

Hence, probability being $50%$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

To be found is $P\left(U+V>K\right)$ where $U$ and $V$ are iid and have 
uniform distribution on $[0,K]$.

Now observe that $K-U$ and $K-V$ also are iid and have 
uniform distribution on $[0,K]$ so that:$$P\left(U+V>K\right)=P(K-U+K-V>K)=P(U+V<K)$$

Combining this with:$$P\left(U+V>K\right)+P\left(U+V<K\right)$$ we conclude that:$$P\left(U+V>K\right)=\frac12$$

Btw: WLOG we can solve this for $K=1$. That is actually enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this in terms of probability. Let $X, Y \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim}\mathcal{U}([0, K])$. Then $Z = X + Y$ is a symmetric triangular distribution on the interval $[0, 2K]$, with mean $\operatorname{E}(Z) = K$.

Because the distribution of $Z$ is symmetric, the events $Z > \operatorname{E}(Z)$ and $Z < \operatorname{E}(Z)$ are equiprobable and $P(Z > \operatorname{E}(Z)) = P(Z < \operatorname{E}(Z)) = 0.5$.